# I cannot make group box visible

Tags: c#

Very confused trying to get this to work. I have two group boxes one over the other and depending on what the users presses depends on which will be visible. Easy I thought till I tried, the second box is always hidden by the first invisible one. How do I force it to come to the front and be visible it must be easy?  Please see the solution below which will show in simple terms what I am trying to do.

The scratchpad solution can be found at https://ufile.io/exo9v

Comment: the radio buttons have to be inside (child) the group box to work.  So there is no way you can have the same radio button be a child of two different group boxes.

Comment: Are you shure the second group box is not a child of the first one? Because this what happens if you drag it on top of the first one in the designer.

Comment: *"Please see the solution below"* - I don't see solution, but some download link. Consider to [edit] relevant code (see [mcve]) into question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line in your designer.cs file:

```
 this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.groupBox2);
```

this makes groupBox2 a child of groupbox1. You haven't put one groupbox over the other, you have made the second one a child of the first.
If you hide the groupbox1 you hide also all its children, groupbox2 included.

I suggest to put the second groupbox in a separate place on the surface of your form, so you can easily work with it and its controls at design time.
In the form constructor, after the InitializeComponent call, just set the Location property of the second groupbox equal to the Location property of the first one

```
 public Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
          groupbox2.Location = groupbox1.Location;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that one line fixes it and I have learned something new.